# Sql Server 2008 installation error : Attempt to perform an unauthorized operation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I had sql server 2008 r2 express edition in my PC .But i unistalled it ,In order to install Sql server 2008 Enterprise edition trial version in my PC.
But some features in sql server 2008 showing "attempt to perform an unauthorized operation" error during installation process.

[image]

My operating system is windows 7 home basic 64 bit.

these are the feature which are showing error while installation:

- sql server database engine service
- sql server replication
- sql server analysis services

please help me with this issue

Comment: Did you try running the setup as administrator?(Right click > Run as administrator)

Comment: no........i thought it is a registry error @StephanCalderon

Comment: Whenever I see unauthorized, it make sure its not an admin issue. This person had the same problem and someone shows you how to fix the registry http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83681/setup-error-attempted-to-perform-an-unauthorized-operation

Comment: i tried the solution given in that link but its not working @StephanCalderon

Comment: I too got the same error while installing sql 2014, i solved it by moving sql 2014 setup to C drive then run as administrator

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64548757/attempted-to-perform-an-unauthorized-operation-when-executing-sql-server-2019-se

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple things to try from people who have had similar problems:

Check: %\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm

Copy installation files to disk and run from there.

Run setup as administrator.

Create a new local administrator account and use that to run the installation.

When error occurs, dont exit installation, run process monitor trace, click retry for installation, stop trace, locate registry key where where access denied is, give your account temporary full control on that key, retry again.

**Use the slipstream procedure to update SQL Server 2008**

This method allows you to update the entire product when you run the SQL Server 2008 Setup program after following one of the following procedures:

**Procedure 1: Basic slipstream steps**

Follow the following steps to create a slipstream drop that you can use for installing the original media and a service pack at the same time.

Install the following prerequisites for SQL Server 2008.

**.NET Framework 2.0 SP2 for SQL Server 2008 Express Edition**
You can obtain the .NET Framework 2.0 SP2 from the following Web site in Microsoft Download Center:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=5b2c0358-915b-4eb5-9b1d-10e506da9d0f&displaylang=en

**.NET Framework 3.5 SP1 for other editions**
To download and install the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1, visit the following Microsoft Web site:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=120550

**Windows Installer 4.5**
To download and install Windows Installer 4.5, visit the following Microsoft Web site:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=49112

Download the **latest service pack** package that matches you system architecture. For example download the x64 package of SQL Server 2008 Service Pack 1 if your system is an x64-based system.
Extract the service pack by running the following command: 
SQLServer2008SP1-KB968369-x64-ENU.exe /x:C:\SP1
Run the service pack to install Setup files on the computer. You will receive a Setup Support Files dialog box if the Setup support files have not been installed. You can also run the following file to install the setup support files: 
C:\SP1\x64\setup\1033\sqlsupport.msi

**Finally,**
run the Setup.exe file from the SQL Server 2008 source media by specifying the /PCUSource parameter. For example:
Setup.exe /PCUSource=C:\SP1

Comment: I dont know how to run process monitor trace @Stephan Calderon

Comment: Did you try the other things?

Comment: You could try the slipstream method mentioned above. It's worked for some according to my google searches. Sorry I can't be more help

Answer (score 0):

I have been googling for this issue a lot but there were no solution working for me. atlast , I formatted my system for a fresh install which worked fr me.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple.

1 - Install **ONLY** "Sql Server Database Engine"

2 - Start installation again and add any other features to your instance

P.S. No need to run as Admin or in Windows 7 compat-mode (if you are installing on 8 or 10)

Answer (score 0):

In my Case, creating an Administrator Windows Account and installing SQL Server worked!
Also you can simply activate the built-in windows Administrator Account by running the **"net user administrator /active:yes"** command in command prompt(Admin Mode), then log in as Administrator. Now You can Install SQL Server without problem!
Finally I should say that you can use SQL Server from your own normal windows account after Installation and I recommend deactivating Administrator Account by **"net user administrator /active:no"**