# Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation when executing SQL Server 2019 service pack

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2019, servicepacks

I already had SQL Server 2019. After upgrading my Windows 10 to latest October Update, I found my SQL Server does not have latest service packs.
I downloaded latest service pack CU8 from Microsoft and ran it. After initializing set up, I get error

```
Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation
```

[image]

Many research and no luck even in SO.

Please advise.

Comment: When launching the downloaded setup executable are you right-clicking on it and choosing "Run as Administrator"?

Comment: Yes, I do. but it doesn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing the logs and digging into windows registry and security, I found the problem was "Microsoft Edge" registry key. Somehow it is read-only for administrator and I figured it out I need to use SYSTEM account to apply the service pack.

Finally I found I can do that using an executable in SysInternals package which is famous for doing weird things in Windows.

This is what I did to apply the service pack.

1. Run Cmd or PowerShell as Administrator
2. Go to SysInternals and make sure you have the PsExec64.exe there
3. Run below command:

> .\PsExec64.exe -sid "D:\Downloads\SQLServer2019-KB4577194-x64.exe"

This way you will execute the service pack using SYSTEM account which has highest privilege.

Service pack installed successfully!

Comment: Can you clarify which specific registry key?

Comment: Possibly related - I had the same error and then found there was an update available for Microsoft Edge 86.0.622.56. After that installed I retried the SQL CU and it's working now

Answer (score 1):

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/business/download

Please get the offline installer for latest Microsoft Edge (Chromium) on above link.

Once you have it, run Edge installer and then try to run SQL Update again.

This worked. I ran the latest Edge standalone install and it unblocked the MSSQL patch.

I also confirm that it works. Thanks

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/business/download

I can confirm this fixes the issue when trying to install SQL 2014 Express Advanced on Windows 10 with H2 update installed.
I had the same error, and installing the standalone Microsoft Edge fixes the error.